# Bug Report? Links with period used to work for folders within doc libraries, but is no longer working

Tags: sharepoint-online, links

I am sure that links with period worked at one point for folders previously, as it did for all my previous work. But when I checked again recently after one of my stakeholders reported some broken links, it was found that the period is now breaking all folder links that appeared to be links (via list view webparts). Are other people experiencing this? Or is this appearing to be something quite unique to my current site?

Example:
Doc Library A has the following folders

```
/Folder B/Folder.C/

/Folder B/Folder D/
```

List B >
Has column with links, some will work and some will not work

Works previously, now broken:

```
/XXX/Lists/List A/Folder B/Folder.C
```

Works previously, and still does:

```
/XXX/Lists/List A/Folder B/Folder D
```

This site is a 365 site on Sharepoint Online.